# Updating values in a nested dictionary is updating other values in the same level

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested

```
print (d['merged'])
# {'a': {'size': 'huge', 'angle': '0', 'above': 'b'}, 'b': {'size': 'huge', 'angle': '0', 'above': 'b'}}

d['merged']['a']['angle'] = 700
print (d['merged'])
# {'a': {'size': 'huge', 'angle': 700, 'above': 'b'}, 'b': {'size': 'huge', 'angle': 700, 'above': 'b'}}
```

Both `'angle'` values in keys `'a'` and `'b'` get updated even though I'm specifically assigning the value `700` to `'a'`.
How do i update just `a` or `b`'s `'angle'` values independently?

Comment: Your code is correct. It is your code before this that causes this. Probably, you've set `d['merged']['a']` and `d['merged']['b']` to the same dictionary.

Comment: thanks, fixed it by adding .copy() when creating d['merged'] from another dict